# Using Cookies to Capture UTM URL Parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, utm

I read the following post to understand how to use cookies to capture UTM URL Parameters:

https://jennamolby.com/how-to-use-cookies-to-capture-url-parameters/

I genuinely think that the code she outlined has all the write steps, but that it wont actually work. Getting this in Stackoverflow so that we can update the code and so that we can update the author so that others (like myself) do not have issues going forward.

Parse the URL

The URL parameters need to be parsed so the cookie values can be set. This can be done using javascript.

```
// Parse the URL
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&amp;]" + name + "=([^&amp;#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
// Give the URL parameters variable names
var source = getParameterByName('utm_source');
var medium = getParameterByName('utm_medium');
var campaign = getParameterByName('utm_campaign');
```

Setting the Cookie Values

In order to set the cookie values, jQuery and the jQuery Cookie Plugin must be on the page.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/path/to/js.cookie.js"></script>
```

Using the variables defined in the first step, the cookie values can be set.

```
// Set the cookies
if($.cookie('utm_source') == null || $.cookie('utm_source') == "") {
$.cookie('utm_source', source);
}
if($.cookie('utm_medium') == null || $.cookie('utm_medium') == "") {
$.cookie('utm_medium', medium);
}
if($.cookie('utm_campaign') == null || $.cookie('utm_campaign') == "") {
$.cookie('utm_campaign', campaign);
}
```

Then we grab the cookie values and set the form field values

```
// Grab the cookie value and set the form field values
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=utm_source').val(utm_source);
    $('input[name=utm_medium').val(utm_medium);
    $('input[name=utm_campaign').val(utm_campaign);
});
```

I have the following questions:

1. Does Jquery still support cookies?
2. I am confused about the below code. I do not think this will work, because it is not reading the cookie values.

   // Grab the cookie value and set the form field values
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('input[name=utm_source').val(utm_source);
       $('input[name=utm_medium').val(utm_medium);
       $('input[name=utm_campaign').val(utm_campaign);
   });

Shouldn't the code be the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        / Put the variable names into the hidden fields in the form.
        $('input[name=utm_source]').val($.cookie('utm_source'));
    $('input[name=utm_medium]').val($.cookie('utm_medium')_;
        $('input[name=utm_campaign]').val($.cookie('utm_campaign'));
}
```